# extract city list from a country using google places database (districts in Hong Kong)

Tags: google-places-api

I actually saw others post similar questions saying it is not possible to get lower level data (e.g. city) out of a higher level query (e.g. country) using the google places API, but I will try my luck again here in case there was changes recently and become possible.

The reason I ask is I want to populate a list of districts/areas in Hong Kong (Hong Kong is already a city, and it is divided into districts then areas, typed "administrative_area_level_2" & "neighbourhood" respectively in returned JSON from google places API) I find no other databases have such information except for google places API and I really hope it is possible to extract data from it.